# segmentio/parquet fails to read files written with Julia and/or Python

Tags: python, go, parquet

The code below, which was taken almost verbatim from the [segmentio/arrow](https://github.com/segmentio/arrow), fails to read .`parquet` files written with Python and/or Julia libs.  When the code returns from the call to `parquet.ReadFile("file")` the rows contain `0` values for `int64` or `""` for strings. The reading fails with `codec = {ZSTD, GZIP, or SNAPPY}`

```golang
type FiRowType struct{ x1, x2, x3 int64 }
func RdFiFile() {
    rows, err := parquet.ReadFile[FiRowType]("fileName_ZSTD.parquet")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    for _, c := range rows {
        fmt.Printf("%+v\n", c)
    }
}

type FsRowType struct{ x1, x2, x3 string }
func RdFsFile() {
    rows, err := parquet.ReadFile[FsRowType]("fileName_ZSTD.parquet")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    for _, c := range rows {
        fmt.Printf("%+v\n", c)
    }
}
```

The Golang code does not return an error, i.e., err == nil.
The code returns the right number of rows and columns, some info in the metadata seems to be correct (like the originator of the file, date of creation etc).  I created the files using Julia:

```
using Parquet
function WrForGo( )
  min = 1 
  max = 10
  # arrays of size (10,3). ai is int and as is 
String 
  ai = Array{Int64, 2}(undef, 10,3)
  as = Array{String, 2}(undef, 10,3)
  for i =1:max
      for j=1:3
        as[i,j] = string(i, pad=2) * "_" * string(j,pad=2)
        ai[i,j] = (j-1)*10 + i
      end
    end

    dfi = DataFrame(ai, :auto) ; dfs = DataFrame(as, :auto)
    print( dfi ) ;  print( dfs )
    Parquet.write_parquet( prqDir * "fi_ZSTD.parquet", compression_codec = "ZSTD", dfi)
    Parquet.write_parquet( prqDir * "fs_ZSTD.parquet", compression_codec = "ZSTD", dfs)

    Parquet.write_parquet( prqDir * "fi_GZIP.parquet", compression_codec = "GZIP", dfi)
    Parquet.write_parquet( prqDir * "fs_GZIP.parquet", compression_codec = "GZIP", dfs)

    Parquet.write_parquet( prqDir * "fi_SNAPPY.parquet", compression_codec = "SNAPPY", dfi)
    Parquet.write_parquet( prqDir * "fs_SNAPPY.parquet", compression_codec = "SNAPPY", dfs)

end
```

Comment: It an error is being returned then it's unsurprising that `rows` contains default values. Can you please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (i.e. Python code to generate a file and the full Go code you are using to attempt to read it).

Comment: The code returns no error msg, i.e, err == nil. The code fins the right number of rows and columns, and the  right data types for each column. However when you enter the for loop to print the rows, the rows have zero values.

Answer (score 0):

In Go variables that start with a lower case character [not exported](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers) so cannot be updated from other packages (e.g. `segmentio/parquet-go`). Try the below:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/segmentio/parquet-go"
)

type FiRowType struct {
    X1 int64 `parquet:"x1,optional"`
    X2 int64 `parquet:"x2,optional"`
    X3 int64 `parquet:"x3,optional"`
}

func RdFiFile() {
    rows, err := parquet.ReadFile[FiRowType]("fi_ZSTD.parquet")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    for i, c := range rows {
        fmt.Printf("%d %+v\n", i, c)
    }
}

func main() {
    RdFiFile()
}
```

Comment: Yes, that was it. I completely forgot that Go only exports variables that start with upper case letters. I guess this happened to me because I am going back and forth between several languages. Thank you much ! ! !